# vector subscript out of range, printing out vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
 #include <iostream>     
 #include <fstream>     
 #include <vector>
 #include <iterator>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
     vector< vector<char> > MyVector;
     ifstream infile("text.txt", ifstream::binary);
     ofstream outfile("new.txt", ofstream::binary);

     if (infile) {
        // get length of file:
        infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
        int length = infile.tellg();
        infile.seekg(0, infile.beg);

        char * buffer = new char[length];
        cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";
        // read data as a block:
        infile.read(buffer, length);

        if (infile)
            cout << "all characters read successfully.";
        else
            cout << "error: only " << infile.gcount() << " could be read";

        MyVector.resize(1);
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            if (buffer[i] == ' ' && '\n') {
                j++;
                MyVector.resize(j + 1);
                MyVector[j].push_back(0x0D);
                MyVector[j].push_back(0x0A);            
            }
            else {
                MyVector[i].push_back(buffer[i]);
            }           
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MyVector.size(); i++) { 
            outfile.write( &MyVector[i][], 1);
        }

        infile.close();
        outfile.close();
        // ...buffer contains the entire file...
        getchar();

        delete[] buffer;    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to read the text file into the vector and then create a new file so it is a little modified.

I don't really understand how to print it out.

I guess there's something very wrong with this loop:

```
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < MyVector.size(); i++) {
        outfile.write(&MyVector[i][j], 1);
    }
```

Probably something wrong somewhere else too.

Right now i'm getting : "vector subscript out of range error.."

Comment: What are you trying to modify?  `if (buffer[i] == ' ' && '\n')` is always true for one thing, and `MyVector.size()` is the number of vectors contained in `MyVector`, not the length of each of those vectors.

Comment: In the .txt file i got just some random words. In the new text file I'm trying to get each word to start with a new line

Comment: That's nice, but it didn't answer my question at all.  What modification are you trying to perform?  It is not evident from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems. Here are some:

```
if (buffer[i] == ' ' && '\n')
```

you probably mean:

```
if (buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == '\n')
```

Here:

```
MyVector[i].push_back(buffer[i]);
```

you probably mean:

```
MyVector[j].push_back(buffer[i]);
```

Here:

```
outfile.write( &MyVector[i][], 1);
```

you probably mean:

```
outfile.write(&MyVector[i][0], MyVector[i].size())
outfile.write("\n",1)
```

Also notice that you are reinventing the wheel (which might be a nice exercise, if it is an exercise). In fact you should use std::string and std::getline to read a text file line by line

Comment: yes this is an exercise indeed. that helped me a bit, gonna try to repair the code and if i still got problems/questions and i'm sure i will then i'm gonna come back. anyway thank you Paolini